# Does Associated Legendre Function of Second Kind Give Delta Function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dirac-delta, singularity, legendre-functions

Associated Legendre Function of Second Kind is singular at $x=\pm 1$. So I am wondering whether it satisfies the corresponding differential equation everywhere or there is a hidden functional of delta function on the right hand side of the equation. For example, consider the equation
\begin{equation}
\left((1-x^2)f'(x)\right)'+(2-\frac{4}{1-x^2})f(x)=0
\end{equation}
which has a solution $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ singular at $x=\pm1$. The reason I ask this is an example of electric potential produced by a point particle and we have the equation
$$\nabla^2\frac{1}{r}=\delta^3(r)$$
As one can see, the function $h=1/r$ satisfies $\nabla^2h=0$ everywhere except $r=0$. Actually, we have a delta function $\delta(r)$ as the source or inhomogeneous term of the differential equation. Therefore, I want to know if something similar happens to the associated Legendre function of second kind.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, and this applies to all Sturm-Liouville-type problems on finite intervals, with Dirichlet boundary conditions. Namely, as you observe, the classical formulation only refers to satisfaction of the differential equation on the *interior* of the interval... and since the solutions/eigenfunctions, extended by $0$ outside the interval, are *not* smooth at the endpoints, something "non-classical" must happen at the endpoints. Depending on the specifics of the situation of course, with Dirichlet condition, the multiples of Dirac $\delta$s at the endpoints are essentially the values of the one-sided derivative at those endpoints.

Comment: +1 any goog rederence to share Paul ?

Comment: @Aryadeva, no, unfortunately I do not know of any standard reference for this phenomenon. Classical sources do not seem inclined to introduce distributions, and modern sources seem uninterested in re-consideration of these simple classical situations. But it's easy to work out examples, such as $\Delta$ on $[0,2\pi]$ with boundary conditions $u(0)=u(2\pi)=0$. The eigenfunctions are $\sin(nx/2)$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$. Extending by $0$ outside $[0,2\pi]$ gives non-differentiability at the endpoints. Extending by periodicity gives non-differentiability at endpoints for _half_ the eigenfunctions...

Comment: Thanks a lot Paul for this comment and answer.